# Bottom Navigation with Flutter

Tags: dart, material-design, flutter, bottomnavigationview

I try to build a App with flutter and have a problem by building the navigation. I want to have a navigation like in the current version of youtube app. A Bottom Navigation Bar with three Pages and than for each Page sub Pages with an owen navigation stack. On all subpages it shoud be possible to change the main view and the app shoud save on witch subpage i where. Is that possible? I found no solution for that. I think it shoud be possible because its on the example page of material Design: https://material.io/design/components/bottom-navigation.html#behavior at the Point "Bottom navigation actions".
I would be so thankful for help!

Comment: this may be relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49781227/flutter-update-bottomnavigationbar/49781672#49781672

to save the scroll you may want to look at `PageStorageKey`
https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/PageStorageKey-class.html

Comment: Personally I would watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EyLqj9L_Tck

Comment: hmmm... maybe a little bit more specific? so overall it sounds like something I have written in a demo for a post. Feel free to take a look at the post https://medium.com/@jacksonzhou666_71188/build-a-game-with-only-flutter-bottomnavigationbar-e87ce5c73bf7?source=friends_link&sk=daac837094f647bd205731343f847df0

Answer (score 2):

I'd take a look at [this code snippet](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16221#issuecomment-389407234) for help.

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:my_nit2018/navigarion_drawer.dart';
import 'package:my_nit2018/pages/app/blog/blog_page.dart';
import 'package:my_nit2018/pages/app/home/home_page.dart';
import 'package:my_nit2018/pages/app/library/library_page.dart';
import 'package:my_nit2018/pages/app/notifications/notifications_page.dart';

class MainApp extends StatefulWidget {
  FirebaseUser user;

  MainApp(this.user);

  @override
  _MainAppState createState() => new _MainAppState();
}

class _MainAppState extends State<MainApp> {
  int i = 0;
  var pages = [
    new HomePage(),
    new BlogPage(),
    new LibraryPage(),
    new NotificationsPage()
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: pages[i],
      drawer: new AppNavigationDrawer(),
      bottomNavigationBar: new BottomNavigationBar(
        items: [
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.home),
            title: new Text('Home'),
          ),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.photo_library),
            title: new Text('Blog'),
          ),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.book),
            title: new Text('Library'),
          ),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.notifications),
            title: new Text('Notifications'),
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: i,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            i = index;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

AppNavigationDrawer:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:my_nit2018/pages/app/app_state.dart';
import 'package:my_nit2018/pages/app/main_app.dart';
import 'package:my_nit2018/pages/app/profile/profile_page.dart';
import 'package:my_nit2018/pages/auth/login_page.dart';

class AppNavigationDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppNavigationDrawerState createState() => new 
  _AppNavigationDrawerState();
}

class _AppNavigationDrawerState extends State<AppNavigationDrawer> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final appState = AppState.of(context);
    return new Drawer(
      child: new ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: <Widget>[
          new DrawerHeader(
            child: new Text('MyNiT App'),
             decoration: new BoxDecoration(
             color: Colors.blue,
        ),
      ),
      new ListTile(
        title: new Text('Todo List'),
        leading: new Icon(Icons.list),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      ),
      new ListTile(
        title: new Text('Subscriptions'),
        leading: new Icon(Icons.subscriptions),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      ),
      new ListTile(
        title: new Text('Activity'),
        leading: new Icon(Icons.timelapse),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      ),
      new ListTile(
        title: new Text('Profile'),
        leading: new Icon(Icons.account_circle),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            new MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => new AppState(
                    firebaseUser: appState.firebaseUser,
                    user: appState.user,
                    child: new ProfilePage(),
                  ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
      new ListTile(
        title: new Text('Logout'),
        leading: new Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
        onTap: () {
          // Sign out user from app
          FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
          Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
              new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new LoginPage()),
              ModalRoute.withName(null));
        },
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

}
}

Comment: The interesting thing about this code is the drawer. But what did he implement in the AppNavigationDrawer class? The rest of the code i have the same but with that you can't make sub pages like the guy on github say. And i can't use Cupertino because it's just for ios. So se interesting thing is whether the drawer provides this functionality.

Comment: To clarify, Cupertino is not just for iOS, it can be used on Android too!

Answer (score 0):

Try this Simple Bottom Bar

```
[import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

/// This Widget is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyStatefulWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static const TextStyle optionStyle =
      TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
  static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>\[
    Text(
      'Index 0: Home',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 1: Business',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 2: School',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
  \];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('BottomNavigationBar Sample'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>\[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text('Home'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.business),
            title: Text('Business'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.school),
            title: Text('School'),
          ),
        \],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber\[800\],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}][1]
```

[Check this image for Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHxPd.png)